# Tracking order in which Pthreads finish

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I have a process which spawns two threads. I want to know which thread finishes first and which one finishes last. I am new to C programming and Pthreads. 
I have gone through the docs of 'pthread_join' but not sure how that can be used.

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Pthreads as a library doesn't provide any tools to achieve this goal.

Comment: If you care about this, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: First, you would have to precisely define what you mean by ' finishes first' and so, with only two threads, 'finishes last'.  What is 'finished'?   When the thread function executes a return?  When the kernel code then gains control?  When the thread's stack and TCB have been deallocated?  When some other thread waiting on termination is  made ready?  When some other thread waiting on termination is  made running?  When that thread makes some decision on 'thread A finshed first/last'?

Comment: 'I am new to C programming and Pthreads' no kidding.  You should design threaded systems so that the order of completion is 'don't care', else you will end up down some horrible multithread rabbit-hole and end up in the 'never use threads, they are too dangerous' prison camp where so many otherwise-competent developers are already incarcerated, too afraid to be released into the community.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. One is simple, but requires that the thread not call `pthread_exit`. The other is more complex, but supports the use case where the thread may call `pthread_exit`.

In both cases, you need some function that reports the thread's termination. This should be very simple to write -- acquire a mutex, update some shared structure with information about which thread is terminating and when, and then release the mutex.

Simple method: When you construct the thread, pass it a wrapper function that calls the termination reporting function after the regular thread function returns.

Complex method: Use `pthread_key_create` to create a TSD key whose destructor reports thread termination. When you construct the thread, pass it a wrapper function. The wrapper function should create an instance of the TSD data whose destructor reports thread termination.

I'm assuming you really do want/need to do what you say you want to do. Most likely there's a better way to solve your actual outer problem, but you didn't tell us what that problem is.

Comment: ' pass it a wrapper function that calls the termination reporting function after the regular thread function returns' well, one thread, (call it 'A'), function call could complete its work first and then get interrupted/preempted as it executed the return instruction, but before it managed to acquire the mutex.  The other thread, 'B', could finish its work much later but still get to the mutex before thread A.  This is a silly requirement from OP, and difficult to define, never mind implement.

Comment: @MartinJames He didn't ask about knowing what work was done first. He asked how to tell which thread finished first. As I said, if his actual outer problem is something else, other solutions are better. In the case where the two thread terminations overlap, either result has to be considered correct.